# Jenkins script execution and output display

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to execute several scripts located in our Linux directories and display the script's output (preferably) as console output.

So far, I have created a project for this task, selected `execute shell` from `Add Build Step` and write in the script path from the `vm` it is located in. The build passes successfully, but I do not see any output on console output, so I'm not sure if the script works or not.

Any ideas on this matter would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: You're going to have to paste the code in to the question in order to get any help on this.

Comment: @RobKielty this isn't a question about a specific script or a script written in a specific programming language, as I also described in my question. Lets say; how would you execute and display output of a "Hello World" script located under /home/jenkins directory?

Comment: Is your jenkins build executing on the same VM where your script resides ? you can use echo and find that and even you can restrict jenkins to run that build on specific location, can be your script location

Comment: @prudviraj No, scripts are located on different VM. I can link the scripts to my Jenkins machine's location as well but still they will need to ssh to certain other VM's to operate their tasks.

Comment: All of the required details to get help on your problem are located in your comments. The best place to put those details is in the question itself.

Comment: actually jenkins show your system print in its console by default. In your shell script, give an echo and u will see this echo in jenkins console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have used.

I selected "Execute Shell" form "Add Build Step" and wrote down my command with the following syntax:

**/usr/bin/ssh user@machinename.com "uname -a; id; cd /home/user; ./script1; ./script2.sh"**

Apart from the command I've written above, I shared the ssh keys of "user" with the remote machine that it is going to connect via ssh so that a session opens up with auto login and without prompting for password.

Second key point was the " " marks when I've put my command in between.

For displaying the output in Console Output part, this feature works by default and in addition to it, I've installed **Email Extension** plugin which sends out a mail containing Console Output after every build.